# Why arg is not defined?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
_doAction = [{
closepop: function(){
  console.log( 'call' );
  var parntid = $(this).attr('data-parentid');
  $('#'+parntid).hide();
 }
}];
```

**When i call the method.**

```
$(document).on('click', '.xyz', function(){
  var action = $(this).attr('data-eventname');

  _doAction[0][action].apply(this, args); // when use args getting error (args is undefined). Why?

  _doAction[0][action].apply(this, arguments); // when use arguments no error, working fine.
});
```

**Can someone help me out or explain me why this is happening..**

Comment: why do you expect that it should work with `args` ?

Comment: Because `args` doesn't exist. You've already shown that `arguments` is the array that contains all the arguments passed into a function, not `args`, so what are you confused about?

Comment: @Hacketo, because i am pasing (this) object into the apply.

Comment: @Tamesh what does that have to do with `args` being undefined?

Answer (score 3):

> Because its `arguments` object not `args`

The `arguments object` is a local variable available within all functions;

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in variable named `args` in JavaScript. The built-in variable is named `arguments`, as described here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

> The arguments object is an Array-like object corresponding to the arguments passed to a function.

I'm not sure where you got the idea that `args` should be defined (perhaps from another programming language?), but that is wrong.

Comment: ohh. i don't know the build-in variable, anyway thanks for your comments